# Generating names for output blobs for an Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Using the binding options for an Azure Function one can specify the name of a Blob to be written based on parameters derived from the trigger (e.g. the queue message that triggered the function); the documentation shows an example of that.

My question is: what is the best way to handle the case where the blob name is not known in advance, but in fact is *calculated* as part of the function's execution?

And related: what to do if the function may or may not produce an output blob (or multiple output blobs!), based on the outcome of its calculation?

As far as I can see now Azure Function's binding mechanism doesn't help much in these cases and the easiest approach is to refer to an assembly that does the azure blob writing "the classical way". But is there a more idiomatic way?

Comment: Updated answer with missing information is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855409/how-do-i-use-binder-to-perform-dynamic-bindings-in-my-c-sharp-function).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can actually already to this in C# Azure Functions, and we have a tracking item [here in our repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/85) to enable this for Node.js Functions as well. We'll get to that soon.

Below is an example working function that binds to a blob with the path specified **at runtime**. Since under the covers Azure Functions is built on the [Azure WebJobs SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-webjobs-resources/), you'll notice that this relies on using the WebJobs SDK `Binder` something that you might not be familiar with. Please see the WebJobs SDK for more documentation on `IBinder`/`Binder`. In the WebJobs SDK, declarative attributes are used for bindings (e.g. `QueueAttribute`/`TableAttribute`/`BlobAttribute`, etc.). You can specify all of these at runtime via `Binder`. In Azure Functions, we use external metadata to describe bindings, but in this advanced scenario you have a hybrid. Note that when using `Binder` there is no corresponding binding in `function.json`. For more details on `Binder` dynamic bindings see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855409/how-do-i-use-binder-to-perform-dynamic-bindings-in-my-c-sharp-function) SO question/answer.

In general, you'll find that many awesome WebJobs SDK features are usable in Azure Functions - our doc just needs to catch up to make people aware of this :)

One other thing to note: there is some inbuilt support for generating random new identifiers for outputs. E.g. if you were to set your output blob path to **test-output/{rand-guid}** the system will automatically generate a new ID for you. If that meets your needs, then you don't need `Binder`.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> 
       Run(HttpRequestMessage req, Binder binder, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Verbose($"C# HTTP function processed RequestUri={req.RequestUri}");

    using (var writer = await binder.BindAsync<TextWriter>(
                  new BlobAttribute("test-output/result")))
    {
        writer.Write("Hello World!!");
    }

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

For your second question, if you want to conditionally write to an output binding, just don't assign any value to the binding - no output should be produced.

Comment: Should you have a `using` on the writer to make sure it gets closed?

Comment: cool! I didn't know the IBinder "trick" what i did was: `var container = outBlob.Container; var newOutBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(newFileName);` :$

Comment: @mathewc Does IBinder work for other outputs as well?  I tried doing something similar with SaasFile output but could not get it to work.  The question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39669606/how-can-i-set-a-folder-name-and-file-name-in-azure-functions-saas-file-bindings) if you get a chance.

Comment: @mathewc can you update your answer to include the function.json that matches the code above? I'm trying to more clearly understand how IBinder parameter relates to the blob output binding in function.json.

Comment: Another question: is it %rand-guid% or {rand-guid}? You mentioned %rand-guid% but the documentation says {rand-guid}.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#random-guids

Comment: Binder/IBinder parameters don't have a representation in function.json. I'll clarify my answer above. Also we did change the rand-guid syntax I'll fix that as well. A more descriptive post on Binder scenarios is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855409/how-do-i-use-binder-to-perform-dynamic-bindings-in-my-c-sharp-function

Comment: @mathewc - Is there a way to bind Storage Queues instead of Blob Storage using Azure functions? I tried using the QueueAttribute instead but I am getting an error message when trying to use binder to bind to the queue. CloudQueue outputQueue = binder.Bind<CloudQueue>(queueAttribute); Error : The type or namespace name 'CloudQueue' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Yes, it works for all attributes. You just have to add the correct #r assembly refs and using statements. In this case `#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"` and `using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue`. I mentioned this above in my answer already.

Comment: would love to know what you mean by `just don't assign any value to the binding`??

Comment: if possible, could you please update this answer if you believe there's a more idiomatic way to accomplish conditional output bindings?

Comment: This answer shows how you can use the attribute to set the connection string: https://dev.to/azure/runtime-binding-with-azure-functions-3gno 

    var attribute = new BlobAttribute("messages/{sys.randguid}.txt", FileAccess.Write);
    attribute.Connection = "AzureStorageConnectionString";

Comment: A easy step-by-step example can be found at: https://ianescober.github.io/posts/dynamic-binding-in-azure-functions/ - does need an minor adjustment, since the binder.BindAsync<Stream> now only takes a single attribute (instead of an array), but works like a charm.