# How can I set a folder name and file name in Azure Functions SaaS File bindings?

Tags: c#, azure-webjobssdk, azure-functions

I am trying to use a SaaS File trigger to listen for new files in an FTP site. First of all, can you even define a variable folder, like `"path": "inputTest/{folder}/{fileName}"`? Or, perhaps, listen to new files in all subfolders and include the path in the file name, like `inputTest/{file}` where `file` might equal `"subfolder/fileName.txt"`? The idea here is that I will have multiple clients uploading files into their own directories, and I don't want to create a new function/trigger for each one.

The same thing goes for the output. I want a SasS File binding that can write to various folders. I think I can use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36428165/generating-names-for-output-blobs-for-an-azure-function), but I'll still need to test it out.  The idea is that I want to stream the input file reading a line at a time, process the line in some way, and write it out to another file.  Essentially a transform.  There might be other ways to do this but I would like to understand this binding better.

---

**UPDATE**

I tried the following for the output binding:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;

public static void Run(string input, IBinder output, TraceWriter log)
{
    string connectionStringSetting = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(
        "ftp_FTP", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    var path = "InputTest/SubFolder/fileName.txt";
    log.Info($"Writing to {path}...");
    using (var writer = output.Bind<TextWriter>(
        new ApiHubFileAttribute(connectionStringSetting, path)))
    {
        writer.Write(input);
    }
    log.Info("Done writing...");
}
```

I included the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ApiHub` NuGet package for the `ApiHubFileAttribute`.  I got the error `Exception binding parameter 'output'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ApiHub: Unsupported type:Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.IBinder`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When using `IBinder` you should not have a mapped parameter in your `function.json` file for that parameter. That's why you're getting the error.

Comment: File triggers based on files added to a sub folder of a root folder is not supported and you will need to have a different function/trigger on each sub folder.

Answer (score 0):

The SaaS file trigger binding does not handle monitoring of variable sub paths. The path expression must be of the form `folder/{fileName}` and the file component will only bind to individual files in that specific folder, not sub folders. The static path before the file name can include sub folders, e.g. `folder/subFolder/{fileName}`.

You can use `IBinder` in the way you describe to write one or more files. That should work.

Comment: How often does the file watcher look for new files within that folder?

Comment: The default is 90 seconds, but you can configure that in your binding via the `pollIntervalInSeconds` property. The Functions portal doesn't expose that, you'll have to set that via the Advanced Editor.

Comment: I removed the `out` binding and got the following: `2016-09-27T15:45:23.898 Function started (Id=8db8fc1e-69de-4094-9bd4-a90a64ad0199)
2016-09-27T15:45:23.914 Writing to InputTest/SubFolder/fileName.txt...
2016-09-27T15:45:24.008 Function completed (Failure, Id=8db8fc1e-69de-4094-9bd4-a90a64ad0199)
2016-09-27T15:45:24.039 Exception while executing function: Functions.BlogTriggerOutputTest. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. mscorlib: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
`

Comment: Can you please include your full function code as well as the function.json file, if you still get this error?