# Upload file to blob storage with azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

In my scenario, the function needs to poll a remote service and when new item appears the function should upload a new file to blob storage. There is an example in the documentation of how to save data to blob storage [Blob binding example in Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#innodejs):

```
// Copy blob from input to output, based on a queue trigger
module.exports = function(context) {
    context.log('Node.js Queue trigger function processed', context.bindings.myQueueItem);
    context.bindings.myOutputBlob = context.bindings.myInputBlob;
    context.done();
};
```

But it is not clear how to specify a different name for the uploaded file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the name of the output blob is controlled by the WebJobs SDK you're running atop of. There's no `IBinder` exposed yet for JS to do this imperatively ([like you can do for C#](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp.md#binding-at-runtime-via-imperative-bindings)).

[image: outblob]

[This is a better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39818834) that links to the GitHub issue where the upcoming feature is being tracked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I ended up not using output binding. Instead I use azure storage sdk to upload a file to blob storage. Not sure why would I want to use output binding if there is a complete SDK to work with blob storage.

Comment: This is totally doable now via function.json, see updated docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#output