# How to output multiple blobs from an Azure Function?

Tags: azure-functions

Out bindings has example:

```
ICollector<T> (to output multiple blobs)
```

And also:

```
Path must contain the container name and the blob name to write to. For example,
if you have a queue trigger in your function, you can use "path":
"samples-workitems/{queueTrigger}" to point to a blob in the samples-workitems
container with a name that matches the blob name specified in the trigger
message.
```

And default in "Integrate" UI has default as:

```
Path: outcontainer/{rand-guid}
```

But this isn't sufficient for me to make headway. If I'm coding in C#, what is the syntax for function.json and for run.csx to output multiple blobs to a container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several different ways you can accomplish this. First, if the number of blobs you need to output is **fixed**, you can just use multiple output bindings.

```
using System;

public class Input
{
    public string Container { get; set; }
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Second { get; set; }
}

public static void Run(Input input, out string first, out string second, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"Writing 2 blobs to container {input.Container}");
    first = "Azure";
    second = "Functions";
}
```

And the corresponding function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "manualTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "input"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "first",
      "path": "{Container}/{First}",
      "connection": "functionfun_STORAGE",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "second",
      "path": "{Container}/{Second}",
      "connection": "functionfun_STORAGE",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

To test the above, I send a test JSON payload to the function, and the blobs are generated:

```
{
  Container: "test",
  First: "test1",
  Second: "test2"
}
```

The sample above demonstrates how the blob container/name values can be bound from the input (via the `{Container}/{First}` `{Container}/{Second}` path expressions). You just have to define a POCO capturing the values you want to bind to. I used ManualTrigger here for simplicity, but this works for the other trigger types as well. Also, while I chose to bind to `out string` Types, you can bind to any of the other supported types: `TextWriter`, `Stream`, `CloudBlockBlob`, etc.

If the number of blobs you need to output is **variable**, then you can use **Binder** to imperatively bind and write blobs in your function code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855409/how-do-i-use-binder-to-perform-dynamic-bindings-in-my-c-sharp-function/39855427#39855427) for more details. To bind to multiple outputs, you'd just perform multiple imperative bindings using that technique.

FYI: our documentation was incorrect, so I logged a bug [here](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/180) to get that fixed :)

Comment: I am trying that the imperative pattern. Am getting a compile error - see below.

Comment: // imperative binding to storage
                blobPath = $"json/{fileNamePart}_{dateString}";
                var attributes = new Attribute[] {
                  new BlobAttribute(blobPath),
                  new StorageAccountAttribute(storageAccount)
                };

                using (var writer = binder.Bind<TextWriter>(attributes)) {
                    writer.Write(jsonString.ToString());
                }

Comment: The error:

2017-02-12T00:43:43.243 Function started (Id=6d48c79d-5af3-4c9a-b4ab-242d186e7c33)
2017-02-12T00:43:43.243 Function compilation error
2017-02-12T00:43:43.243 (225,73): error CS1026: ) expected
2017-02-12T00:43:43.243 (225,61): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Attribute[]' to 'System.Attribute'
2017-02-12T00:43:43.243 (161,13): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected
2017-02-12T00:43:43.243 (191,17): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected
2017-02-12T00:43:43.243 Function completed (Failure, Id=6d48c79d-5af3-4c9a-b4ab-242d186e7c33)

Comment: By the way, I think that clicking "Run" should always try to compile the csx file. Currently it does not. Only when triggered do I get the above compile error.

Comment: You're calling the wrong Binder method - please see the example code again. It's BindAsync. You should change your method signature to "async Task" to use that method.

Comment: If I use BinderAsync I get the error that I can't use async in this context. I'll get the full error message in a moment.

Comment: 2017-02-12T19:08:45.309 Function compilation error
2017-02-12T19:08:45.309 (225,67): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Attribute[]' to 'System.Attribute'
2017-02-12T19:08:45.309 (225,37): error CS4033: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: I am using the Run method signature that the portal created for me for a Blob trigger. Can I just change it to async? What is the syntax for that for a Blob trigger?

Comment: Current signature is:

public static void Run(Stream myBlob, string blobname, out string emailQueueItem, Binder binder, TraceWriter log)

Comment: Because you're using out parameters, you can't change your function to async. One option is to wait for the results via GetResult, e.g. binder.BindAsync<T>(...).GetAwaiter().GetResult(). Another option is to change your "out string" binding to use IAsyncCollector<string>, which would then allow your function to be async. You'd then change the signature to return "async Task". The second option would be better.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. What is it that makes the second option better? Just async being better in general?

Comment: It's best not to block synchronously on async Tasks. If you're unblocked now on this, please mark this question as answered, thanks :)

Comment: I'm just trying out your suggestion now.

Comment: Pursued the "Second option" and seems to be working for me

Comment: I spoke to soon. Only works for really small blobs. For larger ones, there is no error and my logging says it was posted to storage. But it never appears in Blob Storage. How would I go about diagnosing this?

Comment: The code:


                blobPath = $"json/{fileNamePart}_{dateString}";
                var attributes = new Attribute[] {
                  new BlobAttribute(blobPath),
                  new StorageAccountAttribute("deal2_STORAGE")
                };

                using (var writer = await binder.BindAsync<TextWriter>(attributes).ConfigureAwait(false)) {
                    writer.Write(jsonString.ToString());
                }

                Logger.Info($"added JSON blob {blobPath}, length {jsonString.Length}");

Comment: Bobs sized around 10K work. Second test had blobs sized around 25K and they never show up in storage.

Comment: I'll start a new question regarding the new issue above since this comment thread has grown long.

Comment: would love an example of how to configure binder to do imperative input bindings, i can only find examples that do output