# Azure Function App: Can't bind Queue to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue' (IBinder)

Tags: azure, f#, azure-functions

My scenario for an Azure function:

1. HTTP trigger.
2. Based on HTTP parameters I want to read messages from an appropriate storage queue and return data back.

Here is the code of the function (F#):

```
let Run(request: string, customerId: int, userName: string, binder: IBinder) =
    let subscriberKey = sprintf "%i-%s" customerId userName
    let attribute = new QueueAttribute(subscriberKey)
    let queue = binder.Bind<CloudQueue>(attribute)     
    () //TODO: read messages from the queue
```

The compilation succeeds (with proper NuGet references and opening packages), but I get the runtime exception:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: 
Can't bind Queue to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue'.
```

My code is based on an example from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to).

What am I doing wrong?

Update: now I realize I haven't specified Connection Name anywhere. Do I need a binding for the `IBinder`-based queue access?

Update 2: my `function.json` file:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "name": "request",
      "route": "retrieve/{customerId}/{userName}",
      "authLevel": "function",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ],
      "direction": "in"
   }
 ],
 "disabled": false
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you're having versioning issues because you're bringing in a conflicting version of the Storage SDK. Instead, use the built in one (w/o bringing in any nuget packages). This code works with no project.json:

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

open Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
open Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue;

let Run(request: string, customerId: int, userName: string, binder: IBinder) =
    async {
        let subscriberKey = sprintf "%i-%s" customerId userName
        let attribute = new QueueAttribute(subscriberKey)
        let! queue = binder.BindAsync<CloudQueue>(attribute) |> Async.AwaitTask
        () //TODO: read messages from the queue
    } |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

This will bind to the **default storage account** (the one we created for you when your Function App was created). If you want to point to a different storage account, you'll need to create an **array of attributes**, and include a `StorageAccountAttribute` that points to your desired storage account (e.g. `new StorageAccountAttribute("your_storage")`). You then pass this array of attributes (with the queue attribute first in the array) into the `BindAsync` overload that takes an attribute array. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855409/how-do-i-use-binder-to-perform-dynamic-bindings-in-my-c-sharp-function) for more details.

However, if you don't need to do any sophisticated parsing/formatting to form the queue name, **I don't think you even need to use Binder for this**. You can bind to the queue completely declaratively. Here's the function.json and code:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "name": "request",
      "route": "retrieve/{customerId}/{userName}",
      "authLevel": "function",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ],
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "queue",
      "name": "queue",
      "queueName": "{customerId}-{userName}",
      "connection": "<your_storage>",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

And the function code:

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

open Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
open Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue;

let Run(request: string, queue: CloudQueue) =
    async {
        () //TODO: read messages from the queue
    } |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: When I tried removing NuGet reference I got `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=8.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).`

Comment: Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue I thought input bindings are not supported for queues... Thanks, I'll try that!

Comment: I tried copy-pasting your 2nd code, but Portal gives me errors about `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` not found and then `We are unable to reach your function app (Not Found). Please try again later`.

Comment: Are you on our latest ~1 Functions version? That code works for me in production on our latest bits. Try creating a new function and using my exact code + metadata.

Comment: Ok, got it working by copy-pasting... Not sure what the problem was.