# Azure Function: Service Bus input binding (not trigger)

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-functions

Is it possible to define an input binding for my azure function to connect to a Service Bus queue/topic?

I can imagine something similar to 
[this syntax for storage queue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42303702/1171619) but I can't make it work for Service Bus yet, and I don't see examples online.

I'm looking to get hold of an instance of `QueueClient` and/or `QueueDescription` class.

The use case for the function is to return queue size based on HTTP trigger and name in query parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No we don't currently support a `NamespaceManager`/`QueueClient` input binding like we do for Azure Queues. However, you can easily do this yourself using the ServiceBus SDK directly in your function, w/o having to pull in any additional packages. E.g.

```
#r "Microsoft.ServiceBus"

using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

public static void Run(string input, TraceWriter log)
{
    var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("<connection>");
    var nsmgr = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
    long count = nsmgr.GetQueue("myqueue").MessageCount;
    log.Info($"Message count {count}");
}
```

Regarding the doc not being entirely correct for storage queues, I had previously logged an issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-templates/issues/410) to address that. I've also logged a new issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1038) for us to expand our ServiceBus binding.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings) table in the overview section, an input binding for service bus queues/topics is not supported.

Comment: Based on same table, Storage Queues input bindings are not supported either, but they are (see the link in question)...