# Optionally writing to blob

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, streamwriter

I am trying to set up an azure function that would write into a blob only if a function is fulfilled. The blob is int he same location as the function, so I am trying to avoid providing a connection string and do this with bindings. I am currently using binding something like the following:

```
[Blob("folder/myFile.json", FileAccess.Write)]Stream writeBlob
```

With this binding, I can write into the JSON file using:

```
if (myCondition)
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(writeBlob)) 
        writer.Write(myContent);
```

This works fine when the condition is true. However, when the condition is false, the file gets empty. Since I am not writing to the stream, I expected the file to stay untouched. Right now my workaround is to have another read binding to the same json and rewrite the file contents.

Comment: You could bind to container CloudBlobContainer instead of blob and create a blob on need basis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic binding in your case. See this post for more information:

- [How do I use Binder to perform dynamic bindings in my C# Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855409/how-do-i-use-binder-to-perform-dynamic-bindings-in-my-c-sharp-function)

So basically you need to:

- Add a `IBinder binder` parameter in your function definition.
- When your condition is `true`, write your file:

  ```
  if (myCondition)
  {
      var binding= new BlobAttribute(blobPath: "folder/myFile.json");
      using (var writer = binder.Bind<TextWriter>(binding))
      {
          writer.Write(myContent);
      }
  }
  ```