# Azure CosmosDB Trigger to update a Collection based on Value in another Collection

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-triggers

I have to update a cosmosDB Collection(let be collection-1) based on value of a column in another cosmosDB Collection(let be collection-2). The collection-1 should be updated with values from other collections like collection-3 and collection-4. i have tried with writing post trigger in Collection-2 but stuck while writing function inside trigger.

Please suggest whether it is possible with CosmosDB Trigger or suggest If there Is any alternative way to achieve this.

I have created a new trigger function for cosmos DB.

Comment: if you want to bind to multiple collections in one azure function, you may be able to do it by using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855409/how-do-i-use-binder-to-perform-dynamic-bindings-in-my-c-sharp-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my knowledge, you could only monitor updates of one cosmos db collection in every single [Azure Function CosmosDB Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function).

In other words, if the column updates in Collection-1 is determined by the updates of Collection 2,3,4,you need to create 3 triggers for the purpose.

In every trigger,please follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#trigger---example) to configure the collection information and use [Cosmos DB SDK](http://ReplaceDocumentAsync) to replace the specific document.

---

Update answer:

Totally agree with the explanations in the comment by @Matias Quaranta,You confused the two kinds of Triggers here.As you mentioned,surely,Azure Function Trigger need to be adopted. Cosmos DB trigger can't monitor any updates with you collection,it is passively triggered.

For example:

If you want to add one column before inserting documents into cosmos db,you could set the trigger name to activate it while you are using insert document cosmos db sdk. This is trigger under cosmos db.

If you want to monitor the updates of your cosmos db collection,then do some businesses, Azure Function Trigger need to be adopted.

Comment: Collection >> Triggers is a totally different thing, those are [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/stored-procedures-triggers-udfs#triggers) triggers. Those Triggers have a similar concept to SQL Server Table triggers. The Azure Functions Cosmos DB Trigger is a serverless component that will let you build Azure Functions that trigger whenever there is new data in your collection: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-functions

Comment: @Antony Please refer to my update answer and Matias's comments.

Comment: thanks @Jay Gong. I have created a function trigger and is working fine.

Comment: @Antony Great,you could mark the answer to end this case.Have a nice day.

Comment: @Matias Quaranta :   can we trigger this function explicitly for data creation and data updating.?

Comment: @Antony no, the Trigger fires for both insert and replace operations.

Comment: @Matias Quaranta.   I have created a trigger function on a cosmosDB collection and obtain data from that as input to the function and updating same data into another collection. But i am not getting the columns with null values in input, Is this expected behavior ? Or all columns including null value should be available as input to the function?

Comment: @JayGong   I have created a trigger function on a cosmosDB collection and obtain data from that as input to the function and updating same data into another collection. But i am not getting the columns with null values in input, Is this expected behavior ? Or all columns including null value should be available as input to the function?

Comment: @Antony are you mapping the documents to a particular class before saving them to the other collection? Does your class contain JsonAttribute configurations to specifically say to not ignore null values?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta   I am doing this from Azure portal only. And I am not mentioning anywhere to ignore null values.

Comment: I guess this place is not really a good place to troubleshoot, since this is also a different question. Could you create a new question, and if possible, add your trigger code and a sample document, and how you are reading the attributes?

Answer (score 0):

I was confused with the collection >>> trigger and Azure function Cosmos DB Trigger.
The solution for my above question is to create a Azure function to trigger cosmos DB.

Create a Resource >>> Compute >>> Function App.

for adding input and output go to Integrate option from the Function App >>> Trigger that you have created.

[Refer the link for function binding:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fcosmos-db%2FTOC.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json)

This function will trigger on the data updates in a single cosmosDB collection.
We can add n number of collections as input and a collection as output.

Below is the function.json file which will auto create at the time of defining bindings:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
      "name": "documents",
      "direction": "in",
      "leaseCollectionName": "leases",
      "connectionStringSetting": "cosmosdb_DOCUMENTDB",
      "databaseName": "connectivityDB",
      "collectionName": "tblEvent",
      "createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": true
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "name": "outputDocument",
      "databaseName": "connectivityDB",
      "collectionName": "tblNewEvent",
      "createIfNotExists": true,
      "connectionStringSetting": "cosmosdb_DOCUMENTDB",
      "partitionKey": "/id",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is the index.js file created:

```
module.exports = function(context, input) {

     var documents = context.bindings.documents;
     var output = [];

     if(!!input && input.length > 0){

       //write your code here

     }

    context.bindings.outputDocument = output;
    context.done();
}
```